# Arriving at $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit of a function

Tags: limits

Is it possible to somehow arrive at the  $\epsilon$-$\delta$  definition of a limit of a function using the  $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit of a sequence?

Comment: Is there an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit of a sequence?

Comment: The epsilon-delta definition of the limit of a function at $x$ is equivalent to the statement that for any $x_n \to x$, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. (The latter statement is really an epsilon-N statement, not an epsilon-delta statement.) This is proven in pretty much any basic real analysis text.

Comment: Can you state, in exact terms, the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limt of a sequence? Seriously, because in the definitions of a limit of a sequence I know, $\\delta$ usually does not appear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes in metric spaces, where continuity is equivalent to sequential continuity : $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l\iff\forall(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ as }x_n\to a,f(x_n)\to l.$$